# Is it possible to send a response from an XPage that uses Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Tags: xpages

My goal is to stream a large response to the browser. I need to minimise the memory use of the XPage so that multiple hits don't bring the server down.
The XPages are set up "XAgent" style with rendering=false.

Has anyone got this working?

**Attempt 1**

According to various HttpServletResponse posts it should be as simple as flushing the writer as you proceed but that wasn't the case. The code below includes a commented section called Experiment1 that I used to deliberately break the response. My logic being that the resetBuffer call should not impact the content I've already "flushed" - but it did. The broken response only included the error message and none of the chunks.There's a good chance that my assumption is wrong of course.The code ran in the afterRenderResponse event.

```
importPackage(java.util);
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

var ec=facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response=ec.getResponse();
var request=ec.getRequest();
var writer=facesContext.getResponseWriter();
try{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        var s="CHUNKCHUNKCHUNK"+i;
        writer.write(s);
        writer.flush();
        response.flushBuffer();
        //EXPERIMENT1
        //if(i==50){
            //throw new Error("FAIL ON PURPOSE")
        //}
    }

}catch(e){
    //EXPERIMENT1
    //response.resetBuffer()

    var errorObj={};
    response.setStatus(500);

    var errorMessage = e.message;

    if( typeof e.printStackTrace !== 'undefined' ){
        var stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace( new java.io.PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
        errorMessage = stringWriter.toString();
    }

    if( typeof e === 'com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException' ){
        errorMessage = e.getNode().getTraceString() + '\n\n' + errorMessage;
    }

    errorObj.status="error";
    errorObj.message=errorMessage;
    writer.write(toJson(errorObj));
}finally{
    if(creport!=null){
        if(debug){
            creport.close(true);
        }else{
            creport.closeOnlyIfIssue(true);
        }
    }
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

**Attempt 2**

My second attempt was pure desperation. It uses the beforeRenderResponse event and writes the chunks according to the HTML1.1 spec. The code below shows the "Transfer-Encoding" header commented out because it results in a zero byte payload. The headers make it though..

```
importPackage(java.util);
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang)

var ec=facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response=ec.getResponse();
var request=ec.getRequest();
var writer=response.getOutputStream();
try{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    //response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked")
    response.setBufferSize(1024);
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        var s="CHUNKCHUNKCHUNK"+i;
        writer.write((Integer.toHexString(s.length())+"\r\n").getBytes("utf-8"));
        writer.write((s+"\r\n").getBytes("utf-8"));
        writer.flush();
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
    writer.write("0\r\n\r\n".getBytes("utf-8"))

}catch(e){
    var errorObj={};
    //response.resetBuffer();
    response.setStatus(500);

    var errorMessage = e.message;

    if( typeof e.printStackTrace !== 'undefined' ){
        var stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace( new java.io.PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
        errorMessage = stringWriter.toString();
    }

    if( typeof e === 'com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException' ){
        errorMessage = e.getNode().getTraceString() + '\n\n' + errorMessage;
    }

    errorObj.status="error";
    errorObj.message=errorMessage;
    writer.write(toJson(errorObj).getBytes("utf-8"));
}finally{
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: I never tried it, but for something like this I would try the servlet way (see http://edm00se.io/xpages-servlets/servlets-handling-data-round-house-kick/ for inspiration). It gives you much more control over the response object compared to XAgents that do part of the response building themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing the response with

```
var response=ec.getResponse()
```

you are getting an instance of *com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse*. It uses internally a buffer/block-mechanism for a better performance, that's why your first experiment does not work as expected.

But if you access the underlying *LCDAdapterHttpServletResponse* directly, it is possible to get the full control for the outputstream:

```
var response=ec.getResponse().getDelegate();
```

Comment: The getDelegate() call did the trick. See my amended code below

Answer (score 0):

```
importPackage(java.util);
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(imtk);

var ec=facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response=ec.getResponse().getDelegate();
var request=ec.getRequest();
var writer=response.getWriter();

try{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
    response.setHeader("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
    response.flushBuffer();

    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        var s="CHUNK"+i;
        writer.println(Integer.toHexString(s.length()));
        writer.println(s);
        writer.flush(); 
    }

    writer.print("0\r\n");
    writer.print("\r\n");
    writer.flush();

}catch(e){
    var errorObj={};
    response.setStatus(500);

    var errorMessage = e.message;

    if( typeof e.printStackTrace !== 'undefined' ){
        var stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace( new java.io.PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
        errorMessage = stringWriter.toString();
    }

    if( typeof e === 'com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException' ){
        errorMessage = e.getNode().getTraceString() + '\n\n' + errorMessage;
    }

    errorObj.status="error";
    errorObj.message=errorMessage;
    var json=toJson(errorObj);
    writer.println(Integer.toHexString(json.length()))
    writer.println(json);
    writer.flush();
    writer.print("0\r\n");
    writer.print("\r\n");
    writer.flush();
}finally{
    if(creport!=null){
        if(debug){
            creport.close(true);
        }else{
            creport.closeOnlyIfIssue(true);
        }    
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```